# Too much space between comment deleter and diamond on deleted comments

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools, whitespace

Mods get a shiny inline display for deleted comments. I just noticed that there is too much space between the comment deleter and their diamond:

[image]

The one at the top is how it *should* look. I did some poking around in the HTML and it looks like someone left an errant space:

[image]

If I change `"Undo "` to `"Undo"`, it looks right. Can we please fix this earth-shatteringly major issue?

Comment: Well, it's not a pluralization bug so you don't have to worry about the giant S...

Comment: @hichris123 Wait, I thought they separated the diamond using a small, transparent S...

Comment: Solution: stop deleting comments and you won't see it.